# Terminal word navigation/deletion

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I'm a bit puzzled by the following keyboard shortcuts in Ubunutu terminal:

- <kbd>**CTRL** + Left</kbd>, <kbd>**CTRL** + Right</kbd> to navigate words
- <kbd>**ALT** + Backspace</kbd> to delete entire word at the left of the cursor

I'm mainly a Windows user, and I'm accustomed to the powershell defaults for the three commands described above: <kbd>**CTRL** + Left</kbd>, <kbd>**CTRL** + Right</kbd>, <kbd>**CTRL** + Backspace</kbd>.

Lately I've been working with putty to ssh into linux machines or with MongoDB shell, where the default shortcuts are: <kbd>**ALT** + Left</kbd>, <kbd>**ALT** + Right</kbd>, <kbd>**ALT** + Backspace</kbd>.

I've had no problem switching between the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>-based keyword combinations so far.

But the Ubuntu terminal settings are a combination of the two, which is quite confusing for me.

Is there a way to change these settings to make them use either <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>, but not both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> 
Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>

So, you have all the controls with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> : removing one word at a time
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> : removing entire line of code at a time
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd> : navigating to left, one word at a time
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd> : navigating to right, one word at a time

Comment: Ctrl+w removes one word until the previous space. How do you remove one word until the previous special character (e.g. `/`, `.`, etc)?